# deleted symlink sudo rm /lib64/libc.so.6, how to address it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

I make a mistaken that delete the **libc.so.6** by `sudo rm /lib64/libc.so.6`.

OS is CentOS 6.4: 
`Linux k20-1 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I try to run the following to rebuild
1 

`sudo LD_PRELOAD=/lib64/libc-2.12.so ln -s /lib64/libc-2.12.so libc.so.6
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Failed.

2 And, it can not rebuild the soft link also:

`[llf@k20-1 lib]$ sudo ln -sf /lib64/libc-2.14.so /lib64/libc.so.6
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

3 I use a statically linked:

`[llf@k20-1 lib64]$ sudo /sbin/sln /lib64/libc-2.12.so /lib64/libc.so.6
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

It's a remote server, I can not Insert the setup disk into the server that set up and restart the computer. And I am not a root, but I I have sudo privilege.

How to address this mistake? Thanks!

Comment: As `sudo` is also a program linked against libc.so.6, you are basically stuck. Do not log out of the server! If you have some way to create a symlink (as user) anywhere, you can try `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/symlink sudo`

Comment: @dseifert The path of sudo symlink is `/usr/bin`. I have added `/usr/bin` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:
```
[llf@k20-1 bin]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/bin:/opt/glibc-2.14/lib:/usr/local/lib: ...
```
But the `sudo` command is still stuck:
```
[llf@k20-1 bin]$ sudo
sudo: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
``` 
What's this problem?

Comment: @dseifert 
And I check the property of `sudo`:
```
[llf@k20-1 bin]$ ll ./sudo*
---s--x--x. 1 root root 123832 Feb 22  2013 ./sudo
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      4 Mar 16  2016 ./sudoedit -> sudo
---x--x--x. 1 root root  59744 Feb 22  2013 ./sudoreplay
```

Comment: BTW, this question may also be more appropriate on http://serverfault.com (SO is for programming questions)

Comment: My suggestion of using LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not applicable, as I forgot that setuid programs (like sudo) ignore it for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I will visit to serverfault.com for help. And should I turn back the initial state before your answer?

Comment: Like delete the ~/libc.so.6 and `export PATH=/home/llf` etc.

Comment: Probably best to avoid confusion.